# Is there a function that takes a list of argument lists and applies each list to a given function?

Tags: function, clojure, arguments, composition

I.e., something like:

```
(defn dowith [f & arglists]
  (doseq [args arglists] (apply f args)))
```

Is there a built-in function like that in Clojure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I write things like that moderately often; its just so short that it's not really worth wrapping:

```
(map #(apply myfun %) list-of-arglists)
```

I use `map` most often so i get the results and keep it lazy. of course if you don't want it lazy and don't want the results then `doseq` is fine also.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no built-in function that does that.